# VBA Calculating difference between this week/last week & this month/last month in pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have an user form,where users can generate weekly reports.

Now I need to calculate and show in this report(red highlighted area),also the difference from last week and last month.

My code is like following;

```
If lboCharts.Value = "Ranking Changes in A-Bucket" And cboType.Value = "Regions" Then

   Sheets("Report").Select

   If lblCounter.Caption = "" Then

       deleteReportSheet

        ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
       "RAW!R1C1:R1048576C20", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
       TableDestination:="Report!R1C1", TableName:="regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket", DefaultVersion _
       :=xlPivotTableVersion14

       With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Month")
           .Orientation = xlPageField
           .Position = 1
       End With
       With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Pagetype")
           .Orientation = xlPageField
           .Position = 1
       End With
       ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Pagetype").ClearAllFilters
       ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Pagetype").CurrentPage = _
           "Region"
       With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Bucket")
           .Orientation = xlPageField
           .Position = 1
       End With
       ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Bucket").ClearAllFilters
       ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Bucket").CurrentPage = "A"
       With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Date")
           .Orientation = xlColumnField
           .Position = 1
       End With
       With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Theme")
           .Orientation = xlRowField
           .Position = 1
       End With
       With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Keyword")
           .Orientation = xlRowField
           .Position = 2
       End With
       ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
           "regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Position"), "Count of Position", xlCount
       With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Count of Position")
           .Caption = "Average of Position"
           .Function = xlAverage
       End With
       With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Domain")
           .Orientation = xlPageField
           .Position = 1
       End With
       With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket")
           .ColumnGrand = False
           .RowGrand = False
       End With
       ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Domain").ClearAllFilters
       ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Domain").CurrentPage = Trim(cboCountry.Value)
       ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters.Add _
       Type:=xlAfterOrEqualTo, Value1:=Trim(tbDate.Value)


       lblCounter.Caption = "1"
       btnGenerateReport.Caption = "Update Report"

   Else   
       ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Domain").ClearAllFilters
       ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Domain").CurrentPage = Trim(cboCountry.Value)
       ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Date").ClearAllFilters
       ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters.Add _
       Type:=xlAfterOrEqualTo, Value1:=Trim(tbDate.Value)

   End If

End If
```

My report should look like this ;

[image: Ranking Changes in A-Bucket]
PS: Column order won't be stable.

I would appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally find out how to do that,

I've added following code,which calculates the difference between the previos week.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Position"), "Count of Position", xlCount

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotFields("Count of Position")
        .Caption = "Weekly Difference"
        .Function = xlAverage
        .Calculation = xlDifferenceFrom
        .BaseField = "Date"
        .BaseItem = "(previous)"
    End With
```

This part is for Icons in the pivot table

```
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("regions_ranking_changes_in_a_bucket").PivotSelect _
                "'Weekly Difference'", xlDataAndLabel, True

    Selection.FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
        .ReverseOrder = False
        .ShowIconOnly = False
        .IconSet = ActiveWorkbook.IconSets(xl3TrafficLights1)
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(1).Icon = xlIconGreenUpArrow
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(2)
        .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
        .Value = 0
        .Operator = 7
        .Icon = xlIconYellowCircle
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(3)
        .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
        .Value = 1
        .Operator = 7
        .Icon = xlIconRedDownArrow
    End With
```

End the result looks like ;

[image: Result]